# Store query results or use nested queries

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query (simplified), that computes `C`:

```
SELECT A + B AS C FROM Foo
```

The query returns 0.5 million rows.

I need to select rows where C < 0.3. To do this I insert the results into a temporary table `#Bar`

```
INSERT INTO #Bar
SELECT A + B AS C FROM Foo
```

And apply the condition

```
SELECT *
FROM #Bar
WHERE C < 0.3
```

According to the execution plan `Table Insert` costs 86%. Is there a better way to get `C < 0.3`?
I've tried a nested query, and it's the same.

Comment: Can't you use where clause like "WHERE A + B < 0.3" ?

Comment: You can't just look at the execution plan percentages (especially since you're comparing a read to a write). The whole thing **has** to total 100%, so it's very likely that one piece *is* going to be more expensive than another portion of the plan. It's relative, and tells you **very little** about the actual execution time of that portion of the query/batch. You have to look at all the information presented to you.

Comment: Well, A + B is actually a CASE with 6 big formulas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the temp table at all, just select what you want:

```
SELECT A, B, C = A + B
FROM Foo
WHERE A + B < 0.3
```

Answer (score 1):

All solutions work fine above. I just added third option with common table expression that serves a view and it is a bit easier to read.

```
;WITH CTE_SELECT AS
(
    SELECT A, B, C = A + B
    FROM Foo
    WHERE A + B < 0.3
)

SELECT * FROM CTE_SELECT
```

Comment: how is this solution any better/Different then what Tim has suggested ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a single query like

```
SELECT C FROM
(
SELECT A + B AS C FROM Foo
) bar
WHERE C < 0.3
```

(OR) Include the condition in `WHERE`

```
SELECT A + B AS C FROM Foo
WHERE A + B < 0.3
```